# Creating Map values in Spark using Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to spark-scala development. I am trying to create a map values in spark using scala but getting type mismatch error.

```
scala> val nums = sc.parallelize(Map("red" -> "#FF0000","azure" -> "#F0FFFF","peru" -> "#CD853F"))
<console>:21: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]
 required: Seq[?]
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val nums = sc.parallelize(Map("red" -> "#FF0000","azure" -> "#F0FFFF","peru" -> "#CD853F"))
```

How should I do this?

Comment: Looks like `parallelize` function  expect `Seq` but not `Map`. If you still need a map, you can cast it to seq : `yourMap.toSeq. _*` - try it.

Answer (score 4):

`SparkContext.parallelize` transforms from `Seq[T]` to `RDD[T]`. If you want to create `RDD[(String, String)]` where each element is an individual key-value pair from the original `Map` use:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val m = Map("red" -> "#FF0000","azure" -> "#F0FFFF","peru" -> "#CD853F")
val rdd: RDD[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(m.toSeq)
```

If you want `RDD[Map[String,String]]` (not that it makes any sense with a single element) use:

```
val rdd: RDD[Map[String,String]] = sc.parallelize(Seq(m))
```

Comment: Thanks to you man will have soon the whole documentation of Spark on SO :)

Comment: I almost choked on my coffee :)

Comment: Thanks zaro322. I was wondering how can i access keys from map? i.e. i tried rdd.keys() but got below 
error error: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] does not take parameters
              rdd.keys()

Any suggestion..

Comment: `rdd.keys` - if method in Scala doesn't take parameters it should be called without parentheses.